# Play audio files in microcontroller (Arduino)

Tags: audio, arduino, dac, arduino-c++

I try to make a Bluetooth speaker with a microcontroller (Arduino, teensy... I don't have a defined model, because I'm considering the frequency)

My question is if I want to put a SD, for reading music stored, the problem is there are library only for ".wav" files, but I want to extend for ".mp3", ".m4a", ".aac" and other.

Exist any library for this? and if is not, How I can do it?

I need to decode an audio files, convert the data in bytes and send it to the DAC.
An example code in C++ will help me a lot, I can created a new library for this.

I don't want use modules, I want to try to do my own circuit.

Edit:
I gonna use a third party microcontroller compatible with Arduino, because I need more capacity for audio.

PDT: I don't know if I had to post this in Arduino o electrict defined, so I put in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teensy base on ARM microcontroller (Cortex-M3 & M4) come with FPU, have capacity for play videos. Teensy is a board compatible with arduino. With DAC and SD slot. [Adafruit have a library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_MP3) for play .mp3 on this board.

Well .mp3 is enough for me, but in the future I want to learn how to decode other audio file formats.

Answer (score 0):

The Arduino does not have sufficient resources to do this. An MP3 decoder needs plenty of memory and floating point support. The AVR processors used for Arduinos have neither of these.

The only way you are going to do this with a Arduino is if you use a module.

Comment: Yes, I know it, but there are some third-party arduino Cortex M3 and M4 microcontroller. Like Teensy or Adafruit Metro compatible with arduino.

Comment: a teensy compatible with arduino